# ProgressBar(Dialog) inside a Button android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-progressbar

Can someone suggest how to implement **progress dialog** inside a `Button`
for example , when I click on submit `Button` then **progress dialog** occurs inside `Button` for showing loading
I don't want to block other **UI** elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go with Nilesh answer or if you're not willing to use third party lib, it is quite easy to write your own. All you have to do is to create a custom view extending RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

This [link](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-custom-views-in-android-tutorial) might might help.

Answer (score 1):

See this link for [Progress Button library](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button)

Include Progress Button in your layout like this

```
 <com.dd.processbutton.iml.ActionProcessButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Sign_in"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            custom:pb_colorComplete="@color/green_complete"
            custom:pb_colorNormal="@color/blue_normal"
            custom:pb_colorPressed="@color/blue_pressed"
            custom:pb_colorProgress="@color/purple_progress"
            custom:pb_textComplete="@string/Success"
            custom:pb_textProgress="@string/Loading" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button

Just add this to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
}
```

And then you can use this code in your .xml:

```
<com.dd.CircularProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/circularButton1"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cpb_white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:cpb_cornerRadius="48dp"
        app:cpb_iconComplete="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        app:cpb_iconError="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        app:cpb_textIdle="@string/Upload" />
```