# How to get JAR from Maven for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

How can we get `jar` files/library files from `Maven` repo. `Maven` provides AAR file. 
I know using Android Studio is best but I am facing some issues with my system, so for some time I have to use eclipse.

I want to get jar file/library project for this project
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button/

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button) and export in to your project and if you want you can create jar easily.

Comment: Thanks Karthik , I downloaded sources.jar file but my project is not detecting it's xml element....http://stackoverflow.com/a/31273696/4488007

Comment: Did you add that module as a dependency in your project?

Comment: In eclipse i added it to build path "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Comment: getting element <com.dd.processbutton.iml.ActionProcessButton> is unknown

Comment: @RahulSaxena I don't exactly why you are getting this errot, but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220200/element-com-google-android-gms-ads-adview-is-unknown

Answer (score 0):

The code you're trying to get is an Android library, and requires some resource to work. You need to download the `res` folder too from [here](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button/tree/master/library/src/main/res) and you need to add it to your project res folder.